# Unresolved reference: launch. I can't write example with kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-coroutines

I am going to learn kotlin coroutines, but i got problem on android studio.

I did need imports of library in gradle, but I got problems with code compiler.

I just can't use launch. Kotlin version is 1.3.50. Error: Unresolved Reference Launch

**Import**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

**Code which I try to use:**

```
suspend fun firstCoroutine(){
        println("Kotlin Start")
        launch(CommonPool){
            delay(2000)
            println("Kotlin Inside")

        }
        println("Kotlin End")
    }
```

**My  build.gradle app file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
//эти файлы используюстя для компиляции, построения и упаковки приложений и библиотек
//настройки для модуля
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "guard_studio.akira.firstcotlinproject"//идентификатор приложения
        minSdkVersion 17//минимальная поддерживаемая версия сдк
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"//версия приложения для гугл плэй
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

//список библиотек подключенных к проекту
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2"
}
```

**build.gradle level project**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because using russian language

Comment: please, translate your question to English

Comment: Привет! Если не знаешь как задать вопрос на английском языке, попробуй спросить здесь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @OussemaAroua I edited post. Sorry, I don't know that it is only english forum

Comment: @AndreiTanana  I did it, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is the wrong natural language (Russian) - **Please translate your post to English so other people can understand you** - I would define your problem like this:

'Can't start a coroutine inside my suspend function'

Answer to that question:

> New coroutines can only be started inside a scope.

Suspend function don't provide this scope. Their feature: they can be called **within** a coroutine. [Please read this introduction into coroutines for more info.](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Introduction%20to%20Coroutines%20and%20Channels/06_StructuredConcurrency)

Easiest solution:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

fun firstCoroutine(){
    println("Kotlin Start")

    GlobalScope.launch(){
        delay(2000)
        println("Kotlin Inside")

    }
    println("Kotlin End")
}
```

Your could also define a runBlocking:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun firstCoroutine() = runBlocking {
    println("Kotlin Start")

    launch(){
        delay(2000)
        println("Kotlin Inside")

    }
    println("Kotlin End")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are following an outdated tutorial. You have to use `CoroutineScope` if you want to use latest version of the coroutines. Just for start you can use `GlobalScope`:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

suspend fun firstCoroutine() {
    println("Kotlin Start")
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("Kotlin Inside")

    }
    println("Kotlin End")
}
```